# Index size relative to machine memory and consequent performance implications for MYSQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have the MySQL schema with hundreds of tables hosted in AWS RDS. The indexes on those tables sum up to more than 60 GB.
The machine hosting the database only has 16 GB RAM.
Will increasing my RAM be a good move to speed up my database queries?
What is the healthy available RAM in relation to the MySQL's index size?
Thank you

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide RAM size suggestion.

Comment: It depends on your activity.  If you are touching all rows of all tables all the time, then 100GB of RAM would be better.  But, in many situations, 16GB is more than enough.  Use the [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) to determine which query is slowest.  It will probably be a clue of whether RAM or something else is the bottleneck.